# Problema con sqrt() en PHP

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema con la función `sqrt()` de PHP, el resultado me lo devuelve de la siguiente manera.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
  $num = 3;
  $val = 6;

  $result = sqrt($num + $val);

  var_dump($result); //RETORNARIA float(3);
?>
```

De esta forma devuelve el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora la duda es ¿Como podría o si es posible hacer que solo muestre el **número** y no ***float()***?

Comment: Intenta con `$result = intval(sqrt($num + $val));`

Comment: Eso devuelve int(3) es decir no es solo el numero.

Comment: Ok, ya entendí. `var_dump()` es una instrucción para testear resultados. Te dice el tipo de dato y el valor del dato. Si quieres mostrar en pantalla un resultado, entonces se usa echo (`echo $result;`) o print (`print $result;`) o print_r (`print_r($result);`) Lo más usual es usar `echo`. Date una vuelta por la documentación de PHP para ver las diferencias http://php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas utilizando la función var_dump que te muestra las propiedades de la variable [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php)

Puedes utilizar echo $result;

Saludos.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, así devuelve solo el numero.

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada ;D